# React testing custom Provider

Tags: reactjs, testing, dom, jestjs

Take this Provider as an example:

```
export const reducer = (state: AuthState, action: any): AuthState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "auth":
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: action.payload.authenticated,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AuthContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const signIn = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      await Auth.signIn({
        username,
        password,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "auth", payload: { authenticated: true } });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "auth", payload: { authenticated: false } });
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        signIn,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I want to test the following:

- I need to ensure that `Auth.signIn` is called
- Ensure that the reducer is called and updates the state properly

I am struggling to implement this. I understand that I can stub the `signIn` method that belongs to the `Auth` object, but how do I actually handle this in my test? I have tried following the async guides on Jest but I can't seem to apply it. I'm not quite sure how to actually *test the provider/consumer*. Like do I render it and create a simple component that calls signIn and stub it with Sinon?

I need guidance here, I'm new to using React hooks and before, done this with class components which made it easier since I could stub the methods directly from a shallowed rendered component using `instance()`.